# Where have the megabytes from my downloaded game gone to?

Tags: downloading

I downloaded heros call game, about 130 MB. All is fine -- but I can't find the 130 MB anywhere on my phone, just about 300 KB.

Where have all the megabytes I downloaded gone to? Probably something obvious, but it's driving me mad!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) to find your files. This app shows you a graph of folders and how much space they are using on your SD Card. It is designed to help you clean out folders that get large, so it would be perfect for your case.

[image: Disk Usage Graph]

Comment: One of my favorite apps and, while I still had my Droid, a "must-have".

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded data for games, mostly are saved in `SD-CARD/Android/data` under a folder with a name matching to package name of the game. Albeit, it may differ across developers. For example, Gameloft games data are saved in `SD-CARD/gameloft`. So, you can check those folders with a file explorer app or when your sd card is mounted on pc.

Answer (score -1):

Usually Games are downloaded to the SD card, so check there, for example using a File Manager app.